# ROS project: "no map received" in RViz despite successful data publishing to /scan topic

Tags: ros, slam, rviz

I'm using an RPLidar A1 sensor to generate a map of the environment using the gmapping node in ROS. I've configured the RPLidar node to publish data to the /scan topic, and I'm using the slam_gmapping node to generate a map from this data.

However, when I visualize the map in RViz using the map topic, I'm seeing the message "no map received" in the status bar. Here are some additional details about my setup:

I'm using a static transform broadcaster to publish the transform between the base_link and lidar_frame frames, and I've added a new static transform broadca[frames.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/216gv.png)ster to publish the transform between the base_link and map frames.
I've checked the output of the slam_gmapping node and there don't seem to be any errors or warnings being output.
I've tried increasing the map_update_interval parameter in the rosparam section of the slam_gmapping node to give the mapping algorithm more time to build the map, but that didn't seem to help.
When running the view_frames command, I can see the following frames being broadcasted: base_link, lidar_frame, and map. The base_link frame appears to be the parent frame of the lidar_frame and map frames.
I'm wondering if there are any other potential causes for the "no map received" message in RViz, and if there are any other troubleshooting steps I could try to get the map to display. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!